# Guava conflicts when using kotlin-script-util (for JSR-223 support) in application that uses gRPC

Tags: kotlin, grpc, jsr223

I have a Spring based web application which uses gRPC to communicate with my middle tier.  I would like to be able to use the kotlin-script-util for the JSR-223 scripting engine.  Being that kotlin-script-util relies on the kotlin-compiler dependency (which uses Guava), I am getting version conflicts with gRPC dependencies.

I see that there is a shaded kotlin-compiler-embeddable jar, but no kotlin-script-util that utilizes this dependency.

Is there something I can do to make these dependencies work together?

kotlin-script-util: 1.1.1
gRPC: 1.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no ready-made solution for this problem. We'll try to address it in one of the next releases. (see [KT-17556](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-17561) for the relevant issue).

As a workaround, you can, for now, compile your own variant of the kotlin-script-utils. Just copy the project, change the appropriate dependency to the kotlin-compiler-embeddable, and then fix a few compilation errors by updating import statements (the `com.intellij.openapi.*` packages are relocated to `org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.openapi.*` in the kotlin-compiler-embeddable.)